# Error in Query - missing FROM-clause entry for table - SQL

Tags: python, sql

How come these commands give me " missing From clause"?!

```
select name,count(path) as num from authors join articles on author.id=articles.author join log on log.path=concat('/article/', articles.slug) group by authors.name order by num desc;
```

```
select title, count(path) as num from articles join authors on articles.author = authors.id join log on log.path = concat('/article/',articles.slug) group by title, path, authors.name order by num desc limit 3;
```

Here is my complete python code tho:

```
import psycopg2
db = psycopg2.connect(database="news")
c=db.cursor()
c.execute("""
    select title, count(path) as num from articles join authors on articles.author = authors.id join log on log.path = concat('/article/',articles.slug) group by title, path, authors.name order by num desc limit 3;

    """)
c.execute("""select name,count(path) as num from authors join articles on author.id=articles.author join log on log.path=concat('/article/', articles.slug) group by authors.name order by num desc;""")
rows=c.fetchall()
print (rows)
db.close
```

The error that shows is the following:
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: missing FROM-clause entry for table "authors"
LINE 1: ...,count(path) as num from authors join articles on author.id=...

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? (I'm guessing either MySQL, Postgres, or SQLite).

Comment: It's postgres.....

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong.  You might want to give us a complete reproducible example, including some sample data.

Comment: have you tried rows=list(c)?

Comment: Possibly its the non-plural *author* in `ON` clause. Make sure it references *author**s***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

author.id should be changed to author**s**.id